# Why does this custom formatter annotation in Spring MVC not work using Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I am using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf.
I wanted to create a formatter annotation that formats an attribute of an object on printing it in the html file.

I wrote a sample project where a formatter annotation is supposed to add 10 to an Integer value.

This is my **class:** :

```
public class NumberObject {
    
@AddTenAnnotation
public Integer intFifty = 50; 
}
```

Here is the **html-file:** :

```
<html >
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<body>
<label th:text=${numberObj.intFifty}></label>
</body>
</html>
```

I created

**-a Formatter:**

```
   public class AddTenIntegerFormatter implements Formatter<Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer parse(String text, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String print(Integer a, Locale l) {
        int newVal = a +10; 
        return String.valueOf(newVal);
    }
}
```

**-an annotation:**

```
@Target(value = { ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface AddTenAnnotation {
}
```

-an **annotation factory**:

```
public class IntegerAnnotationFactory implements AnnotationFormatterFactory<AddTenAnnotation> {

    public Set<Class<?>> getFieldTypes() {
        Set<Class<?>> fieldTypes = new HashSet<Class<?>>(1, 1);
        fieldTypes.add(Integer.class);
        return fieldTypes;
    }

    public Parser<?> getParser(AddTenAnnotation annotation, Class<?> fieldType) {
        return new AddTenIntegerFormatter();
    }

    public Printer<?> getPrinter(AddTenAnnotation annotation, Class<?> fieldType) {
        return new AddTenIntegerFormatter();
    }
}
```

and implemented a **WebMvcConfigurer** where I **registered the annotation factory**.
It is inside of the main-SpringBoot-class:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class FormatterTestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FormatterTestApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
        
        @Override
        public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
            
            registry.addFormatterForFieldAnnotation(new IntegerAnnotationFactory());
        }
    }
}
```

**What I've tried:**

I looked at several tutorials/ sample projects like [spring-mvc-showcase](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mvc-showcase/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/mvc/config/WebMvcConfig.java)/ stack overflow questions.

I tried to adjust them to my needs but it didn't work.

Maybe I overlooked something (rather new to spring)?

I already **debugged** it:

-addFormatters() of WebMvcConfigurer is called, getFieldTypes() of the annotation factory is called

-no methods of the Formatter class are called when I display the html-file.

**So my questions would be**

a) what could I do to make the annotation work ? Am I missing something ?

b)is there a preferred/ different way to create a custom formatter annotation in Spring Boot ? I could not find one ...

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Remove `@EnableWebMvc` from your configuration class, then it still wouldn't work as it would only work when using an input field and using `th:field` not `th:text` as that will just evaluate the expression as is.

Comment: @M. Deinum Thank you! It never entered my mind to check the thymeleaf attribute, as the annotation registering seemed so complicated, I would have just kept rechecking it... I did some further research and I found this:  [thymeleaf github issue](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/223 ) by using the syntax th:text=${{numberObj.intFifty}} Thymeleaf uses the formatter (at least it works for me)!